# Tabbar images on ios13

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios13

In `UITabbarController`, I add the tab images with the padding Top 5 & bottom -5. It looked perfect in ios12 but, when I ran the same code in ios13, the images went down as shown in the figure. I ran the code in XCode 10.2.1

[image]

Also, I removed the padding to 0, now ios13 looks perfect, but in ios12, the tab images went up. as shown in figure

[image]

I cannot find any solution relevant to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to simply put if #available(iOS 13, *) {} statement and make corresponding padding according to the iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follow:

```
if (#available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
  // Your code here for padding Top  & bottom with adjustment for iOS 13

}
else {
 // Your code here for padding Top 5 & bottom -5

}
```